# How to Parse JSON data which is not in a "name:value" format?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I am receiving some JSON data which is not in a "name:value" pair but its something like this:

```
[[\"ManagerID\",\"EmployeeID\",\"Domain\"],[\"2\",\"110\",\"BBU\"]]
```

I am not able to parse this data using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` as I get an error

> "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1."

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and .net framework 3.5. Let me know in case you need more clarification.

Comment: The error message says all. How does your object look like?

Comment: Well I am receiving the above data in a string as it is the way returned by the web service. So what I want to do is parse the above mentioned string and store it in a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume your object is of this class:

```
class MyObject
{
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set, }
}
```

Then your JSON does not match it, your JSON should look like:

```
{"ManagerID": 2, "EmployeeID": 110, "Domain": "BBS"}
```

If you really want to read the above JSON you need:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(yourString);
```

Tried

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>("[[\"ManagerID\",\"EmployeeID\",\"Domain\"],[\"2\",\"110\",\"BBU\"]]")
```

But that is not a *handy* structure...

Comment: Hey Thanks a ton! Really appreciate your quick response. Was stuck with this thing for hours. And yes the JSON is not in a correct format but that's what WebService returns and its not under my control.

Comment: Just a quick question. How do I populate the data to List<MyObject> directly?

Comment: How does the data provided by the WebService look like when it has more than one record/entry?

Comment: Something like this:        `[[\"ManagerID\",\"EmployeeID\",\"Domain\"],[\"2\",\"110\",\"BBU\"]],[\"5\",\"150\",\"SBU\"]]`                                                where the first row defines the ColumnNames and the rest of the rows are actual data.

Comment: I see. Unforunately you will have to do this with a small loop by yourself. Like `for (int i = 1; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) { myList.Add(new MyObject() { ManagerID = Convert.ToInt32(array[i][0]), .. });` Maybe you will have to parse the column names instead if using fixed indices, maybe you have to expect conversion errors and handle them. You must know ;)